# Splitting one line into multiple ones given a separator

Tags: python

I have a file containing one long line:

```
"name surname" <name.surname@example.com>, 'name surname' <name.surname@example.com>, name surname <name.surname@example.com>, "'name surname'" <name.surname@example.com>, surname, <name.surname@example.com>, name <name.surname@example.com>
```

Note that that's 6 different forms.

I am splitting each email address into its own line, and saving the results into another file:

```
import sys

ifile = sys.argv[1]
ofile = sys.argv[2]

with open(ifile) as ifile, open(ofile, "w") as ofile:
    addresses = ifile.readline().split(">,")
    for n, address in enumerate(addresses):
        address = address.replace("'", "")
        address = address.replace('"', "")
        name, address = address.split("<")
        address = "<" + address
        if len(name) > 1:
            name = name.strip()
            name = '"{}" '.format(name)
            address = "".join(name + address)
        if n < len(addresses) - 1:
            ofile.write(address.strip() + ">\n")
        else:
            ofile.write(address.strip() + "\n")
```

Feels to me like hackery so am looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you first removing the quotes and then putting them back?

And why are you removing the brackets and them putting them back?

This does the same thing, except change ' to ". It also doesn't handle commas in names,
so if you have that it won't work. In that case I'd probably use a regexp.

```
import sys

ifile = sys.argv[1]
ofile = sys.argv[2]

with open(ifile) as ifile, open(ofile, "w") as ofile:
    for address in ifile.readline().split(","):
        ofile.write(address.strip() + '\n')
```

Update:

`"surname, name <name.surname@example.com>"` sucks, and that means your format is inconsistent and not parseable without horrid hacks. In that case your code seems OK, although I'd probably do it differently. I would most likely use a regexp to find all cases of commas that are NOT preceded by > and followed by a space to something else, say chr(128) or something like that. I'd then parse the code with my code above, extract the email from withing the brackets, strip all quotes and brackets from the remander, and replace back chr(128) with commas.

And the lastly write that to the outfile.

The difference there is that I don't try to handle a horrid format, I first try to fix the problems. It makes for cleaner code, IMO.

**Update 2:**

I instead replaced the commas that *should* be split on, making it simpler, like so:

```
import sys

ifile = sys.argv[1]
ofile = sys.argv[2]

with open(ifile) as ifile, open(ofile, "w") as ofile:
    data = ifile.read()
    data = data.replace('>,', '>\xF0')
    for line in data.split('\xF0'):
        name, email = line.split('<')
        email = email.replace('>', '').strip()
        name = name.replace('"', '').replace("'", "").strip()
        ofile.write('"%s" <%s>\n' % (name, email))
```

and then I realized I could simplify it even more:

```
import sys

ifile = sys.argv[1]
ofile = sys.argv[2]

with open(ifile) as ifile, open(ofile, "w") as ofile:
    data = ifile.read()
    for line in data.split('>,'):
        name, email = line.split('<')
        email = email.strip()
        name = name.replace('"', '').replace("'", "").strip()
        ofile.write('"%s" <%s>\n' % (name, email))
```

And as this point I'm basically doing what you are doing, but much simplified.

Comment: I'm sorry for forgetting to include the other things that the code must handle. See my updated question.

Comment: I put back the single opening bracket because str.split() removes it from the list elements.

Comment: @Tshepang: Updated the answer.

Comment: I'm not see where he indicates that he needs to parse that terrible version.

Comment: There's 2 cases that your code doesn't handle. Run my code and yours and compare the results. Use the given input line to test.

Comment: I prefer that you split the `replace()` functionality into separate lines, for the sake of clarity.

Comment: @Tshepang: I'm not here to write code for you. I charge $100 and hour for that. You can split that into separate lines yourself. The only difference in output between yours and mine is that you skip the name if it's empty, which I leave as a trivial example for you to handle.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: There is another difference: your code leaves an extra `>` in the output.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: Regarding the $100 thing, it's only fair that you make your code to at least do what mine does, since you are trying to improve it. It makes it easier to compare my code and yours to clearly see the improvements.

Comment: It's interesting that you didn't implement your solution in regexp. May I ask why?

Comment: Can you comment on my `replace` suggestion. Does it make sense?

Comment: This was simpler. I have no comment.

Comment: It seems I pissed you off. The assumption came due to your mention of money. I didn't mean to.

Comment: @Tshepang: No, I just find your follow-up questions weird, including asking me to split the line. You can split the line. There is no requirement that you take my code character by character. And there is nothing to say about that suggestion. If you want to split the line, split the line. I don't understand why you are asking for comments on that. It's like asking for permission to go to the toilet.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: Since this is Code Review (my code is already working), we are looking for best practices, and that includes code clarity. That's why I thought it's worth mentioning that.

Comment: @Tshepang: That doesn't really explain your questions. Sorry.

Comment: Instead of doing: `name.replace('"', '').replace("'", "").strip()` you should be able to do `name.strip("'\" ")` for the same effect, see: http://docs.python.org/library/string.html?highlight=strip#string.strip.

Comment: @Kit: Yeah, good point, didn't think of that.